# Telegram Botfather should delete his old message

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have a telegram group in which I have integrated the BOT Botfather.
This brings a message to the group twice a day.
I have implemented this in Ubuntu with Python:

```
import telegram 

#Create record
record = "Test"

#Telegramm Bot
api_key = 'MyKey'
user_id = 'USERID'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=api_key)

bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=record)
```

This all works great. But...
Every 12 hours the update comes.
Thus, the "old" message from 12 hours ago is no longer relevant.

Is there a way within the Python code to tell the bot to delete the "old" message?

I can delet Messages with:

```
bot.deleteMessage('CHAT_ID','MESSAGE_ID')
```

I can use the MEssage_ID
https://api.telegram.org/BOTID/getupdates

to find out.

But in the API the ID numbers of the messages of the bot are not in there.

I have already spent many hours on google and can not find what can help me ka
Or I'm just looking for the wrong terms

Comment: Wait, I forgot something:

Of course I know how to delete messages:

Comment: I have now found the solution myself via a Telegram group:

```
res = bot.send_message(chat_id=chatid, text='test')
try:
    print(res.message_id)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

With print(res.message_id) the message_id is returned in python